# Plotting two graphs with subplot involving random variables

Tags: matlab, random

I am trying to plot two graphs of the Wiener process (see code below) with random variables, how can i get matlab to plot one graph, and then recalculate and replot with a different random number, because currently this produces two identical graphs.

```
T=1;
n=100;
dt=T/n;
random=randn(1,n); 
dW=sqrt(dt)*random;
W=cumsum(dW);
t=0:dt:T;
W=[0,W];
figure;
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(t,W); xlabel('Time'); ylabel('W(t)'); title('Simple Wiener process a)'); grid    minor;  
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(t,W); xlabel('Time'); ylabel('W(t)'); title('Simple Wiener process b)'); grid minor;
```

So i want to plot two graphs on the same figure of this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `randn` twice, once you've assigned the output of `randn` to a variable it won't change. So basically the simplest way is to just rewrite all you code from lines 4 - 8 after the first time you `plot`.

However a quicker method in your case would just be to create a random vector with 2 rows:

```
n=100;
dt=T/n;
random=randn(2,n); 
dW=sqrt(dt)*random;
W=cumsum(dW);
t=0:dt:T;
W=[[0;0],W];
figure;
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(t,W(1,:)); xlabel('Time'); ylabel('W(t)'); title('Simple Wiener process a)'); grid    minor;  
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(t,W(2,:)); xlabel('Time'); ylabel('W(t)'); title('Simple Wiener process b)'); grid minor;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about plotting one graph, recalculating, and then replotting with a different random number? ;p

```
T=1;
n=100;
dt=T/n;
random=randn(1,n); 
dW=sqrt(dt)*random;
W=cumsum(dW);
t=0:dt:T;
W=[0,W];
figure;
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(t,W); xlabel('Time'); ylabel('W(t)'); title('Simple Wiener process a)'); grid    minor; 
random=randn(1,n); 
dW=sqrt(dt)*random;
W=cumsum(dW);
W=[0,W]; 
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(t,W); xlabel('Time'); ylabel('W(t)'); title('Simple Wiener process b)'); grid minor;
```